# Как ускорить выдачу результата 16 задачи из ЕГЭ?

Tags: python

Просто я написал программу по заданию:
Функции F(n) и G(n) заданы следующими строчками:

```
F(1) = G(1) = 1,
F(2) = G(2) = 4,
F(n) = 5 * F(n - 1) - G(n - 2) + 8 * n - 15, при n > 2,
G(n) = 2 * F(n - 2) + 3 * G(n - 1) - n * 2, при n > 2.
```

В ответ запишите сумму цифр значения, возвращаемого функцией G(n), если в неё передать аргумент n = 53.
Вроде ошибок в задании нет, но ответ он не выдал спустя уже 20 минут. То ли что-то неправильно написал, то ли огромная сумма цифр получается.

```
def f(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n==2:
        return 4
    else: 
        return 5*f(n-1)-g(n-2)+8*n-15

def g(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n==2:
        return 4
    else:
        return 2*f(n-2)+3*g(n-1)-n*2
print(g(53))
```

Comment: Ну рекурсия у вас, видать, бесконечная.

Comment: Получается, что так. Тогда скажу челу, что задание плохое ему дали.

Comment: Задание-то как раз неплохое. Просто оно требует сначала думать, и только потом делать. А решение влоб как раз кончается сверхдлительным процессом решения.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Лайфхак для ЕГЭ: используйте [`lru_cache`](https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-functools-python/dekorator-lru-cache-modulja-functools/)

```
from functools import lru_cache


@lru_cache(None)
def f(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 4
    else:
        return 5 * f(n - 1) - g(n - 2) + 8 * n - 15


@lru_cache(None)
def g(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 4
    else:
        return 2 * f(n - 2) + 3 * g(n - 1) - n * 2


print('Число:', g(53))
print('Ответ:', sum(map(int, str(g(53)))))
```

Число: 391294163594391175455446622030378362

Ответ: 152

Comment: Красивое решение, поставил плюсик. Кстати, с 1k!

Comment: Спасибо, сам так на ЕГЭ решал, не подвело.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, здесь рекурсия не нужна, а, возможно, мешает.
Делаем 2 списка по 2 элемента, организуя [простые очереди](https://codechick.io/tutorials/dsa/dsa-types-of-queue), в которых сохраняем результаты вычислений f и g, далее рекуррентно подставляем прошлые результаты в текущие формулы.

```
def G(num):
    if num < 1 or not isinstance(num, int):
        raise ValueError('Функция определена только для натуральных чисел')
    f, g = [1, 4], [1, 4]
    for n in range(3, num + 1):
        f.append(5 * f[1] - g.pop(0) + 8 * n - 15)
        g.append(2 * f.pop(0) + 3 * g[0] - n * 2)
    return g[num > 1]


x = G(num := 53)
print(f'''Результат функции G({num}) = {x}
Cумма цифр значения, возвращаемого функцией G({num}) = {sum(map(int, str(x)))}''')
```

```
Результат функции G(53) = 391294163594391175455446622030378362
Cумма цифр значения, возвращаемого функцией G(53) = 152
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def outer_f():
    f1 = 1
    g1 = 1
    f2 = 4
    g2 = 4

    def inner_f(n):
        nonlocal f1, f2, g1, g2
        if n == 1: return f1
        if n == 2: return f2
        f = 5 * f2 - g1 + 8 * n - 15
        g = 2 * f1 + 3 * g2 - n * 2
        f1 = f2
        f2 = f
        g1 = g2
        g2 = g
        return g

    return inner_f


def res(m):  # Получаем результат функции
    fn = outer_f()
    for i in range(3, m):
        fn(i)
    return fn(m)


def sum_l(d):  # Сумма цифр полученного числа
    return sum(map(int, str(d)))


an = res(53)
print(an)
print(sum_l(an))
```

---

```
391294163594391175455446622030378362  # Результат функции
152                                   # Сумма цифр полученного числа
```

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к ответу **@ИванИпатов**.

`lru_cache(None)` можно заменить на `cache`.

У `lru_cache` есть аргумент - максимальная длинна кеша. Если указать `None`, она будет не ограничена.

Но у `cache` она не ограничена по умолчанию.

Так что вот код:

```py
from functools import cache


@cache()
def f(n):
    ...


@cache()
def g(n):
    ...

...
```